# Django : how to change button color based on value _list

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I want to change a button color based on values from my database.
I'm using this code :

```
                  {% if result %}
                  {% for of in result %}
                  <a  data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"  data-content='NO OF: {{of.0}} _ Jour ATT: {{of.2.days}} _ Date Entrée: {{of.1}} '>
                    <span class="{% if '{{of.2}}' > 2 %} dot red {% endif %}
                      {% elif '{{of.2}}' == 2 %}dot red {% endif %}
                      {% else %}dot{% endif %}"></span> 
                  </a> 
                  {% endfor %} 
                  {% else %}
                  <p>Encours Vide</p>
                  {% endif %}
```

i used aslo:

```
 <a  data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"  data-content='NO OF: {{of.0}} _ Jour ATT: {{of.2.days}} _ Date Entrée: {{of.1}} '>
                   {% if '{{of.2}} >=3' %}<span class="dot red"></span> 
                   {% elif '{{of.2}} ==2' %}<span class="dot yellow"></span> 
                   {% else  %}<span class="dot"></span> {% endif %} </a>
```

both doesn't work, how can I check values list in my html code correctly?

Views.py:

```
result=Poste.objects.filter(Nom_poste='MGP1').values_list('OF__Numero_Of','OF__Date','OF__Nbre_jr')
```

PS :I used also `{{of.2.days}}` because `Nbre_jr` is a `DurationField`

css code of dot:

```
.dot {height: 30px; width: 30px;background-color: #0f5132;border-radius:50%;display:inline-block;} 
.red{background-color:#d00000;}
.yellow{background-color: #ffc107;}
```

I don't know how to do this in JS, so tried to simplify my code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use `{}` and `'` in your condition

I mean:

`{% if of.2 > 2 %}`

And don't think that work too

what is `of.2`? maybe you mean `of[2]`?

What kind of data is `of`?

Please explain more if you could not fix with these details

Comment: `of `  is a list result of my  `django.objects.values_list ` . I thought I should use {{ --}} to check elements values of my list.  {% if of.2 > 2 %} it works. I appreciate your help